# Generic Interface and Class example

Tags: java, class, generics, interface

I have defined a simple generic interface:

```
public interface I1 <A> {
    public void display1(A x);
}
```

and a simple generic class:

```
public class c11<A> implements I1<A> {

    @Override
    public void display1(A x) {
        System.out.println(x + " is of type " + x.getClass());
    }
}
```

When I try to instantiate as follows, I get an error:

```
int x = 5;
c11<Integer> s1 = new c11<Integer>(x);
s1.display1(x);
```

Your help is most appreciated.

Comment: what error? On what line?

Comment: Where's your constructor defined?

Comment: [Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the **desired behavior**, a **specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: A remark on your code: classes in Java (like interfaces and enums) always start with an upppercase letter.

Comment: Does it work if you change `new c11<Integer>(x);` to `new c11<Integer>();` ?

Comment: @Turing85 Noted, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It definitely work if you change new c11(x); to new c11();t
As you have not defined any constructor, you can not call parameterized constructor "c11(x)" while instantiating(creating) an object.Still if you want to create object by c11(x) then change the code as follows

```
//interface
public interface I1 <A> {
public void display1();
}

//class
public class c11<A> implements I1<A> {
A x;
public c11(A obj){
  x=obj;  
}

@Override
public void display1() {
    System.out.println(x + " is of type " + x.getClass());
}
}

// and calling code
int x = 5;     
c11<Integer> s1 = new c11<Integer>(x);
s1.display1();
```

make sure that one java file can have only one public class or interface.

Comment: Please fix your code indentation.

Comment: Okay. I will take care of code indentation.

Comment: Thanks. Could you let me know why you removed the argument from display1 method?

Answer (score 4):

Your `c11` class has no constructor that takes an `int` argument (or an `Integer` or the generic type parameter `A` or anything else that would match the `new c11<Integer>(x)` call).

Adding the constructor:

```
c11 (A a) {
     ...
}
```

will resolve the issue.

Comment: What is it supposed to do with that `a`, though? Only OP can tell... If not necessary, we could also remove the argument from the constructor call. But then, why is the class generic (instead of the method)?

Comment: @Thilo yes, only the OP can say what the constructor is supposed to do with `a`.

Comment: Not sure what OP is referring to. I was just practicing to learn how I can define a generic class and interface.

Comment: @MelanieA OP is referring to you (the Original Poster of the question)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and your reply. Could you tell me what should replace the ... in the cosntructor?